# How to use getAttribute to pass a value defined in a component rather than aframe tags attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, components, aframe, getattribute

### Problem:

Within the aframe component `score`, I need to fetch the current `time` value from the component `timer` to calculate the score.

However using the `getAttribute` method returns either a `NaN` value or `[object Object]`.

I have tried passing the `time` variable from `timer` to `score`, however the value of `score` is either not changed or also displayed as `NaN` or `[object Object]`. I'm fairly new to js and aframe so apologies if my code is messy.

Note:
Many entities have not been included in question the code for the sake of simplicity.

### JS Components:

```
         AFRAME.registerComponent('timer', {
                schema:{
                    value:{default: 60},
                },

                init: function B() {
                    var data = this.data;
                    var el = this.el; 
                    var time = 60;
                    if(time == 60 || time == 0){
                        start_b.addEventListener('click', function() {
                            setInterval(() => {
                                if(time > 0){
                            time--
                            el.setAttribute('text', 'value', time);};
                            }, 1000);
                    })}
                }});

            AFRAME.registerComponent('score', {
                  schema: {
                    el: {type: 'selector'},
                    score:{type: 'int', default: 0},
                },

            init: function () {
                var newScore = 0;
                var sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene'); 
                var scoreBoard = document.querySelector('#score_t');
                sceneEl.querySelector('#mix_b').addEventListener('click', () => {
                    var colorOutput = document.querySelector('#box');
                    var colorFrame = document.querySelector('#colorBox');
                    var timeDisplayV = document.querySelector('#timeDisplay');
                    var timeDisplayn = timeDisplayV.getAttribute('text', 'value');
                    var colorAsked = colorFrame.getAttribute('color');
                    var colorMade = colorOutput.getAttribute('color');

                    if(colorMade == colorAsked){
                        var timeDisplayn = timeDisplayV.getAttribute('text', 'value');
                        this.data.score = timeDisplayn
                        newScore = 'Score: ' + this.data.score
                        scoreBoard.setAttribute('text','value', newScore);
                    }
                });

                clear_b.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    el.setAttribute("color", "#ffffff");
                    });
                }
            });
```

### HTML Tags:

```
            <a-entity 
                id="score_t"
                text="value: Score: 0"
                position="0.7 0.45 -1" >
            </a-entity>

            <a-text 
                id="timeDisplay"
                timer="value:" 
                position="0.7 0.65 -1" 
                scale="0.3 0.3 0.3">
            </a-text>
```